# Bibtex4word, revtex4, and AIP style

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to get the AIP bst files to word with `bibtex4word`. I am new at pretty much all of it. I was using the word references but it does not have many styles, including Applied Physics Letters. I am using MikTeX 2.9, JabRef 2.9.2, and `Bibtex4word`. I have my references in JabRef. I am able to use `Bibtex4word` with the default styles (plain, alpha, `IEEEtran`) but am having a hard time installing the new styles.

I downloaded the files here: http://publish.aps.org/revtex then copied the "required" files as described in the Readme in the appropriate directories. I used MikTeX program manager to install the `Revtex` package and styles. I was then able to get the styles to work in `bibtex4word`, sort of. The `aipnum4-1` style should use a superscript number for the reference and should be a minimal bibliography. The data in the bibliography seems to work right but there is a ton of extraneous stuff (like the category labels). I've included a "plain" and an `aipnum4-1` example below using the `Test4w.doc` file included with the `Bibtex4word`.

Have I done something wrong in my setup? Is this a problem that others have? How do I fix it? Is there a better AIP-APL `bibtex` package that might work?

This is what I get using "plain" style:

```
Citation List

[1, 2, 3, 4]

Bibliography

[1] Bob Ollerton, Bill Ollerton, and Barnaby Ollerton. Dynamic stabilty in rapid turn manoevres. Journal of Broomstick Design, 52(4):273–282, January 1926.
[2] Claude E. Shannon. Juggling with quafffles. In Proc. Warlock Juggling Federation Convention, pages 384–389, Hogsmeade, January 1975.
[3] Kennilworthy Whisp and J. K. Rowling. Ancient broom games, chapter 2, pages 3–6. In [4], 2001.
[4] Kennilworthy Whisp and J. K. Rowling. Quidditch through the ages. Whizz Hard Books, 2001.
```

This is what I get using the "aipnum4-1" style:

```
Citation List

[[Ollerton, Ollerton, and Ollerton(1926), [Shannon(1975), [Whisp and Rowling(2001a), [Whisp and Rowling(2001b)]

Bibliography

[[Ollerton, Ollerton, and Ollerton(1926)]   author author B. Ollerton, author B. Ollerton,  and author B. Ollerton, 10.1598/JBD.52.4.1 journal journal Journal of Broomstick Design volume 52, pages 273–282 (year 1926)NoStop%
[[Shannon(1975)]    author author C. E. Shannon, in @noop  booktitle Proc. Warlock Juggling Federation Convention (address Hogsmeade, year 1975) pp. pages 384–389NoStop%
[[Whisp and Rowling(2001a)] author author K. Whisp and author J. K. Rowling, title Ancient broom games, Chap. chapter 2, pp. pages 3–6, in [[Whisp and Rowling(2001b)] (year 2001)NoStop%
[[Whisp and Rowling(2001b)] author author K. Whisp and author J. K. Rowling, @noop  title Quidditch through the ages (publisher Whizz Hard Books, year 2001)NoStop%
```

Answer (score 2):

I emailed the author of bibtex4word (Mike) and he replied:

> Some bibtex styles use Latex commands that Bibtex4Word doesn’t
>   understand. I add extra commands on an as needed basis. When I get a
>   chance I will add the commands needed for the revtex styles.

I worked around this by using a different style to get the appropriate inline citation style, used Miktek to generate the references, then cut and paste them into MSWord. Unfortunately styling (superscript, bold, italics) got lost between the bibtex output PDF and MSWord.